# catching exceptions in C/C++ while using cURL lib

Tags: c++, exception, curl

I am working on a C++ program, which uses cURL library, which is written in plain C.
When I try to connect to an incorrect URL address with cURL handle I get such an exception :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
```

and my program terminates instead of skipping this URL and going futher. 
Here is snippet of my code:

```
CURL* curl;
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, "incorrect URL" );

curl_easy_perform( curl ); // this method throws the expection
```

I tried to handle it like this :

```
try{
   curl_easy_perform( curl ); 
} catch { std::logic_error &e){
    return -1; // skip this URL and go futher
}
```

But still program terminates and it seems that exception is not handled properly.

The file "stdexcept" is included.

Does anyone knows some more about this error and how to catch this exception properly so I my program can keep on working?

Comment: attach a debugger and post the stack trace when the exception is thrown.

Comment: did you check to see if `curl_easy_setopt()` is the one throwing the exception and not `curl_easy_perform()`?

Comment: No I didn't. Good point. I will check it after I go back from new years eve party and post result.

Comment: I checked it and everything's good with setopt. I've posted whole code in another topic, here is the link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696201/curl-couldnt-resolve-host-how-to-deal-with-that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a libcurl expert, but don't you need to assign the result of  `curl_easy_init()` to your `curl` variable before calling the next two curl functions?

ETA, the following code does not throw an exception for me. The `curl_easy_perform` return is `CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6)`.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    std::cout << curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "incorrect URL") << std::endl;
    std::cout << curl_easy_perform(curl) <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Of course you need to do that. I created similar topic with whole method, which had about 50 lines of code and nobody answered. So I decided to post it in a shorter form like this.. Everything with libcurl is set properly I mean if I invoke curl_easy_perfom with correct URL I get that page and do some stuff connected with it. I just don't know how to catch that exception..

Comment: I know it's frustrating not to get an answer to the other question, but you are going to get comments like mine when you post code that can't work (here `curl` is an uninitialized pointer value). Can you boil this down to the simplest example you can that exhibits the same exception that your actual code encounters? FWIW the exception seems to be an attempt to initialize a std::string with a NULL char pointer. Since libcurl does not (AFAIK) use any C++ string objects, there is likely to be something else going on.

Comment: You were right about that string error - it was not cURL's fault. After failed connection I was attempting to assign null ( no connection = no document fetched ) to a string, which was supposed to be the result of this method. That was the case of logic_error, I've already fixed it, but I am still getting that couldn't reslove host error from cURL. I posted whole code in another topic :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696201/curl-couldnt-resolve-host-how-to-deal-with-that