# cURL couldn't resolve host How to deal with that?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am working on a C++ program, which uses cURL lib. When I try to connect to URL, that is incorrect or the page is down I get following error :

- getaddrinfo(3) failed for www.wp.pl#:80
- Couldn't resolve host 'www.wp.pl#'

And the program terminates. And that is the problem, because I it to go futher and connect to other pages. I just won't parse and analyze the broken page I don't want to end my program after come across such one.

I posted similar topic, but it contained only snippets of code so it was diffcult for you to say what is wrong, now I will post whole code.

```
  int PageHandler::getCleanAndRepairedPage(string pageURL, string& outDoc)
    throw (exception) {

if (find(visitedPages.begin(), visitedPages.end(), pageURL)
        != visitedPages.end()) {

    // url has already been visited
    outDoc = "";
    return VISITED_PAGE_ERROR;

} else { // new url

    visitedPages.push_back(pageURL);

    char *charURL;

    charURL = const_cast<char*> (pageURL.c_str());

    CURL *curl;

    char curl_errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

    TidyBuffer output = { 0 };
    TidyBuffer errbuf = { 0 };
    TidyBuffer docbuf = { 0 };

    TidyDoc tdoc = tidyCreate(); // Initialize "document"
    tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyForceOutput, yes);
    tidyOptSetInt(tdoc, TidyWrapLen, 4096);
    tidyBufInit(&docbuf);

    int rc = -1;
    Bool ok;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, charURL );

    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curl_errbuf );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_cb );
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt( curl , CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &docbuf );

    int err;

    err = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    cout << "curl_easy_perfom return value = " << err << endl;

    if (!err) {

        ok = tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyXhtmlOut, yes); // Convert to XHTML

        if (ok) {

            rc = tidySetErrorBuffer(tdoc, &errbuf); // Capture diagnostics

            if (rc >= 0) {

                rc = tidyParseBuffer(tdoc, &docbuf); // parse the buffer
            }
            if (rc >= 0) {

                rc = tidyCleanAndRepair(tdoc); // Tidy it up!
            }
            if (rc >= 0) {

                rc = tidyRunDiagnostics(tdoc); // Kvetch
            }
            if (rc > 1) { // If error, force output.

                rc = (tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyForceOutput, yes) ? rc : -1);
            }
            if (rc >= 0) {

                rc = tidySaveBuffer(tdoc, &output); // Pretty Print
            }
        }

        if (rc >= 0) {

            if (rc > 0) {

                //printf("\nDiagnostics:\n\n%s", errbuf.bp);
            }

        } else {

            printf("A severe error (%d) occurred.\n", rc);
        }

    } else {

        printf("%s\n", curl_errbuf);
    }

    if (err == NO_ERROR) {
        string tmp(reinterpret_cast<char const*> (output.bp));
        outDoc = tmp;
    } else {
        outDoc = "";
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    tidyBufFree(&docbuf);
    tidyBufFree(&output);
    tidyBufFree(&errbuf);
    tidyRelease(tdoc);

    return err; // err == 0 <=> everything ok!

}

}
```

And the console output :

EDIT : I forgot to say what is going on on console output. I connect to many pages and the invalid URL is just one of them. At the beginning you can see a succesful connection and cURL messages about it, the result of curl_easy_perform equals 0, which indicate that everything went good. Next message is about connection to the invalid URL, as u can see return value of curl_easy_perform is 6, which is not good. 
[image: Here u can see console output]

Comment: Can you add printout of what address you are actually passing to curl? I dont think hostname should contain # character - are you putting it there or curl does?

Comment: I pass to it http://www.wp.pl/ as a starting address. Then my program parse that site in search of keywords and extracts all links from it. After that it goes to every extracted link and does the same as before until a certain depth is reached. Address www.wp.pl# is one of the extracted links from starting page.

Comment: Then i am guessing that parsed website contains invalid link - it's not your's program fault that it doesn't work - although obviously you can try to detect and correct this error, once you know about it. PS wp.pl? Miło widzieć że polacy też się udzielają ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"www.wp.pl#" is not a legal URL and it causes libcurl to (mistakenly) use the entire string as a host name, and you don't have any such and the operation fails.

Comment: so I will have to write some url checker, which will check before connection whether url is valid acording to rfc url format ( in libcurl documentation it is written that urls must meet this requirement to be properly handled ). I hoped that there is such a solution that curl can go futher after one/few failed connections, but it seems that if only it encounter invalid url it terminates my whole program. But there is another problem - I checked what happens when the URL is correct, but the page is down - it also terminates the program.

Comment: I think it is likely to come across such a page ( with correct URL, but page not working ) while extracting links from many, many pages. For instance this wp.pl contains about 400 links itself, and then if I extract links from those 400 and again and again I think I will find one with correct URL, but not responding/down/error 404 or with stuff like this. How to deal with that then?

Comment: If you pass in a bad URL to curl, that request will fail. It will not hamper or prevent the next request to succeed if you just pass in a legitimate URL then.

Comment: You are right. My bad was that I tried to free tidyBufs when they hadn't been created because of failed connection. Fixed now. Thanks.
By the way is there any possibility to tell curl not to display info about connection? I connect to a lot of pages and console is heavily spammed.